# Trouble setting up Linq to Entity in c# console application

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Is it possible to get Linq to Entities working with a C# application.. I've done it with my asp.net site, but I can't figure out how to set it up with my new project.

When I click to add in a data connection, the only options are Microsoft Access, SQL Compact edition, and SQL Database file..

Thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What happens when you use "Add New Item" and choose "Entity Data Model"?

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong as there must be no evident difference using EF with ASP.NET app or WinForm ...

Comment: When I select Entity Data Model, it asks me to choose a data connection..  I click on New Connection, but it only gives me two options, Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 and Microsoft SQL Server Database file.  In my ASP.NET web app, I get the option of Microsoft SQL Server..  Any idea how to get it?

Comment: This question is not really related to entity framework! It is an issue with your installation / configuration

Comment: Could this be an issue with using the Express version of Visual c#?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did some thing wrong. I suggest you use the NuGet to add the entity framework to your project. Check the below link

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EntityFramework

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, its exactly the same as my comment on the original question